# How to pull rows from different csv files based on a word

Tags: r, csv

I have 36 different csv files with 8 columns in each.
For each csv file I want to only pull rows that contain the words "liver" and "lung" from the column labeled tissue type.
I then want to write a new csv file for each of the 36 files with only the pulled rows.

I'm trying to see if a for loop will work? I am just still really new to this so I am not sure how to combine it all together.

Comment: is there any reason you can't load the file, and then filter?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this. Note that I cant check this since you didn't provide a reproducible example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

liv_lun_data <- tibble(file = list.files(pattern = "\\.csv")) |>
  mutate(data = map(file, read_csv),
         filtered = map(data, ~filter(.x, `tissue type` %in% c("liver","lung")))) |>
  select(file, filtered) |>
  unnest(filtered)
```